# How can I export a MS Access Database into a PostgresDB, foreign key constraints included?

Tags: postgresql, ms-access

Despite following many guides online recommending the ODBC method (External Data > Export > More > ODBC)  - I've only ever been able to export tables one at a time, neglecting the relationships between the tables throughout the entire database.

Other methods I've used:

- Creating a python script that creates one large SQL Create command, and another that creates one large SQL Insert command. This correctly imports the entire database but doesn't take into account the foreign key constraints

-Used VBA Script that creates an sql file with many CREATE INDEX commands, then ran that file inside my docker container although this script didn't correctly add indexes to the existing database:

```
Sub buildkeysInPG(Optional quoteFields As Boolean = False)
Dim db As Database
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim ndx As DAO.Index
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strFlds As String

Dim fs, f
Dim delimStart As String
Dim delimEnd As String

If quoteFields Then
    delimStart = """"
    delimEnd = """"
Else
    delimStart = ""
    delimEnd = ""
End If


Set db = CurrentDb

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'-- Change this path to where you want script generated
Set f = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\pgindexes.sql")

For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    '-- No system tables or temp tables
    If Left(tdf.Name, 4) <> "Msys" And Left(tdf.Name, 1) <> "~" Then
        'Indexes and Primary Keys
        strSQL = ""
        For Each ndx In tdf.Indexes
            If ndx.Primary Then
                '-- MS Access has a habit of calling all primary keys PrimaryKey
                '-- if you do not explicitly name them
                '-- and key and index names have to be
                '-- unique in PostgreSQL within each schema
                '-- so lets just name it after the table: pk_tablename
                 strSQL = "ALTER TABLE " & delimStart & tdf.Name & delimEnd & " ADD CONSTRAINT " & _
                    delimStart & "pk_" & tdf.Name & delimEnd & " PRIMARY KEY"
            Else
                If ndx.Unique Then
                    strSQL = "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "
                Else
                    strSQL = "CREATE INDEX "
                End If
                '-- Get rid of spaces in index names replace with underscore
                '-- , prefix table name in index name
                '-- because names need to be unique in postgresql
                strSQL = strSQL & delimStart & _
                    "idx_" & tdf.Name & "_" & Replace(ndx.Name, " ", "_") & delimEnd & " ON " & _
                        delimStart & tdf.Name & delimEnd
            End If

            strSQL = strSQL & " ("

            strFlds = ""

            For Each fld In ndx.Fields
                '-- Loop thru the fields of index so this handles compound keys
                strFlds = strFlds & "," & delimStart & fld.Name & delimEnd
            Next

            '-- Get rid of dangling , we introduced
            strSQL = strSQL & Mid(strFlds, 2) & ") "
            
            f.WriteLine strSQL & ";" & vbCrLf
        Next
    End If
Next

f.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: OK. And your question is?

Comment: How can I export a MS Access Database into a PostgresDB, foreign key constraints included?